# Recently, i can't use MongoDB(AWS Amazon EC2)

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I have MongoDB running on AWS. The setup has been up and running for over several months. The application server(server is also on AWS) has been running the same code for several months.

I received a below alert notification January 5 2017 from Amazon.
Then i can't use MongoDB. the mongodb started failing, i tried to change inboud 27017 port in Security Group. But the result was same.

Notification from Amazon is very principle message. So i don't know what i do exactly.

> We are aware of malware that is targeting unauthenticated MongoDB databases which are accessible to the Internet and not configured according to best practices. Based on your security group settings, it appears that your EC2 instances, listed below, may be running a MongoDB database which is accessible to the Internet. If you are not using MongoDB, you may safely ignore this message.
>   We suggest you utilize EC2 Security Groups to limit connections to your MongoDB databases to only addresses or other security groups that should have access.
>   ...

Comment: What do you mean by "started failing"? Can you connect to it by Robomongo, MongoChef, etc? Or is it just your server that cannot access it?

Comment: For the application server access to mongodb - try using the private ip with accessible to port 27017. If you are using mongodb thru the internet, open access to just your ip. For both use CIDR restriction **yourip/32** so that it allows only from your IP.

Comment: when i restart mongodb(sudo service mongod restart)
ubuntu@ip-172-31-2-250:~$ mongod
2017-01-23T04:47:03.509+0000 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2017-01-23T04:47:03.509+0000 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already in use
2017-01-23T04:47:03.509+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets during startup.
2017-01-23T04:47:03.509+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 48
ubuntu@ip-172-31-2-250:~$

Comment: i tried using the private ip with 27017 port, and changed Security groups. but the result was same... T.T